# Tool to monitor my git repositories

Tags: git, dashboard

I'm searching for a tool on Windows that allows me to see all my git repositories in one look and quickly check if I have some uncommited changes on a project or if I forgot to push some commits.

The best would be to have it in a tray icon that changes color if I forgot something, a little bit like CatLight.

Edit: it seems that my question was not clear. I do not want a program to manage one git project at a time. I have like 30 git projects on my computer and I want a tool that allow me to watch **all** my repositories and see quickly if I forgot to commit or to push something in one of my repositories. Some git GUI programs can show if I have unpushed changes, like SourceTree or Github Desktop, but they are heavy and do not show if I have uncommited changes

Comment: You can use editor like visual code , atom  text editor .. they notify the user with different icon inside the software or you can use various plugin available in those tool for that task

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. I agree, it doesn't seem like people reading this are picking up what you're putting down. When you're working in a microservice environment and you have 10 different repos that you're working against, it's easy to forget where you left off and you could forget to check something in.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of GUI clients on the [official website](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows).

I personnaly used [Gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/) and [GitHub for Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), that integrates with Github.

Comment: I tried both, but none of them show if a repository have uncommited changes without opening the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a plugin for [AnyStatus](https://github.com/AnyStatus/AnyStatus) that will monitor your repositories and notify you accordingly. Here are some examples: [AnyStatus Plugins](http://github.com/anystatus/plugins/).

Disclaimer: I am the author of AnyStatus.

Comment: "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site."